# Visual studio 2010 SP1 UI freezes, hangs for some time when you save the code changes

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 20010 Ultimate on Windows 2008 R2 machine. Last week I applied SP1 and after few days I am experiencing UI freeze for some time around 40 to 60 seconds when I save code changes to files.

I have turned off the background compilation, turned off the antivirus still this problem is not going away.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg title and tag say VS 2010

Comment: And there was no Visual Studio 2008 Ultimate :). The version that included everything in VS 2008 was called VSTS

Comment: It would probably help if you report what kind of project you are using. Is it a big solution/many files/etc. In general I haven't noticed perf regressions when I updated VS but I don't know which project types you use.

Comment: It's VS 2010. Sorry for the typo. The problem is seen with any c# project even a basic console app. The problem is seen on 2 machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my 2008 R2 machine I right clicked on the shorcut for VS2010 and selected properties option. In compatability tab I selected to run VS in compatability mode for Windows server 2008 SP1. There is a checkbox and dropdown for this.

For VS 2010 SP1 it is mentioned that it sets software rendering by default. I thought this might be the reason for UI freeze in some case hence I changed the compatibility setting and it seems to be working fine since then!

Answer (score 0):

[With Visual Studio 2012] Try pressing ATL+TAB twice (or switch to another application then switch back to Visual Studio).
That seems to solve the problem.